# Tkinter - create flashing graphic on a canvas?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm using Tkinter (2.7) to try to create a finite loop that draws, then erases a rectangle on a canvas widget, like its flashing. After several days of trying everything I could find, I have to ask for help.

The problem:

The code below seems to create and delete the rectangle inside the program but not display it in the main window (root).

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def make():
    canvas.create_rectangle(20,20,60,60,fill="pink")
    root.after(1000)

def unmake():
    canvas.delete(ALL)
    root.after(1000)   

def loop():
    count = 0 
    while count < 5:
        make()
        unmake()
        count += 1

canvas = Canvas(root,width=100,height=100)
canvas.pack()  

loop()

root.mainloop()
```

Things I've tried:

If I put a print instruction in the make() and unmake() functions these print at 1 second intervals, so I know the .after() method is working.

If I make an infinite loop with the make() function calling unmake() and unmake calling make() again, this does display the flashing rectangle in the main window (root);

```
def make():
    box = canvas.create_rectangle(20,20,60,60,fill="pink")
    root.after(1000,unmake)

def unmake():
    canvas.delete(ALL)
    root.after(1000,make)
```

If someone knows why Tkinter is behaving this way, I'd be very grateful for guidance. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

after() does not call any function in the code posted.  The following code illustrates the basic idea

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def make():
    canvas.create_rectangle(20,20,60,60,fill="pink")
    root.after(1000, unmake)

def unmake():
    canvas.delete(ALL)
    root.after(1000, make)   

canvas = Canvas(root,width=100,height=100)
canvas.pack()  

make()

root.mainloop()
```